# Spark to MongoDB via kerberos

Tags: python, mongodb, scala, apache-spark, kerberos

We have a MongoDB database that is kerberoised. The non-spark connection works fine. You need to specify the uri, create a MongoClient, authnticate yourself in the $external database and for each database. How does it work when the database is behind kerberos. I couldnt find any documentation?

Comment: _"The non-spark connection works fine"_ -- great, so how do you manage Kerberos auth with these? Do you create a implicit ticket first (cf. `kinit`), or do you explicitly login with a keytab, or do you use Windows SSO to login "automagically"??

Comment: Pass in the URI with the kerberos information as per the documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/#kerberos-gssapi

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that might get you in the right direction:

```
# pyspark --driver-class-path "/opt/mongodb-spark-connector/mongodb-driver-3.7.0.jar:/opt/mongodb-spark-connector/mongodb-driver-core-3.7.0.jar:/opt/mongodb-spark-connector/bson-3.7.0.jar:/opt/mongodb-spark-connector/mongo-spark-connector_2.10-1.1.0.jar"

import os

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import getpass
import string
import urllib

try: input = raw_input #for Python 2.x compatibility
except NameError: pass

# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.10:1.1.0 pyspark-shell'

MONGO_HOST = input("Mongo hostname: ") 
MONGO_USER = input("Mongo username: ") 
MONGO_PASSWORD = getpass.getpass('Mongo password:')
DATABASE = input("Database name: ")
COLLECTION = input("Collection name: ")

if '@' in MONGO_USER:
  MONGO_USER = urllib.quote_plus(MONGO_USER) # Python 2
  # MONGO_USER = urllib.parse.quote(MONGO_USER) # Python 3

# LDAP
# MONGO_URI = string.Template("mongodb://${MONGO_USER}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_HOST}:27315/${DATABASE}?&ssl=true&authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=$$external").substitute(locals())

# Kerberos
MONGO_URI = string.Template("mongodb://${MONGO_USER}@${MONGO_HOST}:27315/${DATABASE}?&ssl=true&authMechanism=GSSAPI&authSource=$$external").substitute(locals())

conf = SparkConf()\
    .setAppName("pyspark mongo")\
    .setMaster("local[*]")\
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", MONGO_URI)\
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.database", DATABASE)\
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.collection", COLLECTION)

sc.stop() # stop current shell SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
df = sql_context.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()

df.count()
df.show()
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/carlosmarin/c47bf0335aec660882d2aaaf32850d51

Answer (score 0):

This is my runable demo,hope to help you.

```
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark;
import com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig;
import com.mongodb.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaMongoRDD;
import net.butfly.albatis.spark.constants.Constant;
import net.butfly.albatis.spark.util.PropertiesUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.io.File;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public final class SparkMongoKerberosTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String mongoUri = "mongodb://cdhtest.hik.net:port/kundatabase?&ssl=true&authMechanism=GSSAPI&authSource=$$external";

        try {
            String krbCfgPath = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\kerberos\\";
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", new File(krbCfgPath, "krb5.conf").getPath());
            System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
            System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", new File(krbCfgPath, "jaas.conf").getPath());
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "your realm");
            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "your kdc");
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                    .master("local")
                    .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
                    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://cdhtest.hik.net:27017/")
                    .config("spark.mongodb.input.database","kundatabase")
                    .config("spark.mongodb.input.collection","test1")
                    .getOrCreate();
            SparkConf sparkConf = spark.sparkContext().getConf();
            sparkConf.set(Constant.Spark.SPARK_YARN_PRINCIPAL, PropertiesUtil.getProperty("spark.yarn.principal"));
            sparkConf.set(Constant.Spark.SPARK_YARN_KEYTAB, PropertiesUtil.getProperty("spark.yarn.keytab"));
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.addResource(Constant.YarnConfigFile.YARN_SITE);
            configuration.addResource(Constant.YarnConfigFile.CORE_SITE);
            configuration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
            UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("testuser@HIK.NET", new File(krbCfgPath,"testuser.keytab").getPath());
            UserGroupInformation loginUser = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();
            boolean b = loginUser.hasKerberosCredentials();
            loginUser.addCredentials(new Credentials());
            long customRddU = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().doAs(
                    (PrivilegedExceptionAction<Long>) () -> {
                        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
                        Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        readOverrides.put("collection", "test1");
                        readOverrides.put("uri", mongoUri);
                        ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(readOverrides);  //TODO put ugi
                        MongoSpark.Builder builder = MongoSpark.builder();
                        JavaMongoRDD<Document> customRdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);
                        return customRdd.count();
                    }
            );
            System.out.println(customRddU);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```